# How to filter sub-folder when Walk folder

Tags: go

Now I am using Walk to go through my folder, I want to filter some folder when scan.

```
err := filepath.Walk("/home", func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    ...
})
```

The folder structure is:

```
  home  
 / | \  
a  b  c
```

Can I make some exception list that filepath.Walk **not** scan folder `a`?  That is, I do not want any files in folder `a` add into my scan result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation for [`WalkFuc`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#WalkFunc):

> If an error is returned, processing stops. The sole exception is that if path is a directory and the function returns the special value SkipDir, the contents of the directory are skipped and processing continues as usual on the next file.

So simply make the function you pass to `filepath.Walk` return `filepath.SkipDir` when `path` is the directory you want skipped.

Comment: Was halfway through writing this when you commented :)